# Number Pyramid Nested for Loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm wondering if you could help me out. I'm trying to write a nested for loop in Python 3 that displays a number pyramid that looks like;

```
                              1
                         1    2   1
                     1   2    4   2   1
                 1   2   4    8   4   2   1
             1   2   4   8   16   8   4   2  1
          1  2   4   8  16   32  16   8   4  2  1
       1  2  4   8  16  32   64  32  16   8  4  2  1
    1  2  4  8  16  32  64  128  64  32  16  8  4  2  1
```

Can anybody help me out? It would be much appreciated!

This is what I have so far:

```
col = 1

for i in range(-1, 18, col*2):        

    for j in range(1, 0, 1):
        print("  ", end = "")

    for j in range(i, 0, -2):
        print(j, end = " ")

    print()
```

---

So, I can only get half of the pyramid to display.

I guess the main problems I'm having is:

How do i get the output to display an increasing and then decreasing value (ie. 1, 2, 4, 2, 1)?

Comment: Can you show us your current code and explain what isn't working?

Comment: That's about all I have. If i posted any code that I've been using, you'd probably be boot me off this forum

Comment: It doesn't work like, that. Showing your code helps you and us know what you've tried and where you've erred.

Comment: I can't thank you all enough! All of the below look great!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternate way using list comprehensions.

**Always break the problem down into digestable chunks.** Each line is a mirror of itself, so lets just deal with first making out set of numbers we need.

This generates a list of strings that hold all powers of two which is what this is generating

```
lines = []
for i in range(1,9):
  lines.append([str(2**j) for j in range(i)])
```

But if we just print this list, a) its going to only have half, and b) its going to mush the numbers together. We need to buffer the numbers with spaces. Fortunately, the last row will have the largest digits for any column, so:

Firstly, how long does each line need to end up being (we need this later) and also, what is the longest number in each column. We can use len as we cast the numbers to strings above.

```
b = len(lines[-1])
buffers = [len(x) for x in lines[-1]]
```

Now I have everything I need to print the strings (we stopped using numbers above):

So, for each line, find out how long it is, and expand the array it to the length of the longest line by filling the left of the array with empty strings (for this we're still pretending we're only printing the left half of the triangle):

```
for line in lines:
  l = len(line)
  line = [" "]*(b-len(line)) + line
```

With each line now buffered, we'll make a new array that we will print from. By `zip()`ing together the line and the buffer, we can easily right justify ([`String.rjust()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rjust)) numberic strings, expanded out to the length required.

```
  out = []
  for x,y in zip(line,buffers):
    out.append(x.rjust(y))
```

Remmeber until now, we've still just been working with the left half of the pyramid. So we take the output array, reverse it (`array[::-1]`) and then take every element but the first (`array[1:]`) and join it all together with a string and print it out.

```
  print(" ".join(out+out[::-1][1:]))
```

### Voila! The completed code:

```
lines = []
for i in range(1,9):
  lines.append([str(2**j) for j in range(i)])

b = len(lines[-1])
buffers = [len(x) for x in lines[-1]]

for line in lines:
  l = len(line)
  line = [" "]*(b-len(line)) + line
  out = []
  for x,y in zip(line,buffers):
    out.append(x.rjust(y))
  print(" ".join(out+out[::-1][1:]))
```

Output:

```
                   1                 
               1   2  1              
            1  2   4  2  1           
         1  2  4   8  4  2  1        
      1  2  4  8  16  8  4  2 1      
    1 2  4  8 16  32 16  8  4 2 1    
  1 2 4  8 16 32  64 32 16  8 4 2 1  
1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
height = 8
maxHeight = height - 1
for i in range(height):
    k, Max = 1, i * 2 + 1
    print(maxHeight * "     ", end="")
    maxHeight -= 1
    for j in range(Max):
        print("%5d" % k, end="")
        if (j < (Max // 2)):
            k *= 2
        else:
            k //= 2
    print()
```

**Output:**

```
                                   1
                              1    2    1
                         1    2    4    2    1
                    1    2    4    8    4    2    1
               1    2    4    8   16    8    4    2    1
          1    2    4    8   16   32   16    8    4    2    1
     1    2    4    8   16   32   64   32   16    8    4    2    1
1    2    4    8   16   32   64  128   64   32   16    8    4    2    1
```

Comment: Could you help me understand what exactly is going on with "k" in this. I'm not sure I follow what the; print("%5d" % k, end="") line is doing.

Comment: `k` will be incremented till it reaches the peak and then it will be decremented till the end. The `print` line's `%5d` is like C's `printf`'s format specifier. It is to say that 5 characters are needed to print this number. If the number is lesser than 5 characters, remaining chars will be padded with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

This could be the other 9 line solution.

- Generate power of two's numbers as series
- Find the offset need to add in each rows
- Print the empty space for the each row before printing the palindromic list.
- Ie. (offset * (n - i)) times " "(empty space)
- Build palindromic series by slice operation ie. temp + temp[::-1][1:]
- Print the palindromic series and offset spaces relative to the length of the number you are printing.

Code:

```
n = 8
numbers = [2**x for x in range(n)]                 # Generate interseted series.
offset = len(str(numbers[-1:])) -1                 # Find the max offset for the tree.
for i in range(1, n+1):                            # Iterate n times. 1 to n+1 helps eazy   slicing.
  temp = numbers[:i]                               # Slice series to get first row numbers.
  print(' ' * (offset * (n - i)), end=" ")         # Prefix spaces, multiples of offset.
  for num in temp + temp[::-1][1:]:                # Generate palindromic series for the row.
    print(num, end=" " * (offset - len(str(num)))) # Adjust offset for the number.
  print('')
```

output:

```
                             1   
                         1   2   1   
                     1   2   4   2   1   
                 1   2   4   8   4   2   1   
             1   2   4   8   16  8   4   2   1   
         1   2   4   8   16  32  16  8   4   2   1   
     1   2   4   8   16  32  64  32  16  8   4   2   1   
 1   2   4   8   16  32  64  128 64  32  16  8   4   2   1
```